# Can virtual functions be constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions, constexpr

Can virtual functions like `X::f()` in the following code

```
struct X 
{
    constexpr virtual int f() const 
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

be `constexpr`?

Comment: Think about it a minute. It would completely defeat the `constexpr` purpose.

Comment: Such a hypothetical function could be used as a constant expression only if the complete type of the calling instance is known to be `X`. This would essentially require the language to specify "devirtualization rules".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In D you can do compile time function evaluation with virtual functions. So it's not unthinkable.

Comment: Well, I think it would make sense at least for `final` functions to be able to be `constexpr`.

Comment: Not just for final methods. It could be useful for a compile time unit test. You instantiate a derived class on the stack and use a static_assert on the result of a virtual method. At that point the whole function body could be visible to the compiler.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**This answer is no longer correct as of C++20.**

No. From [dcl.constexpr]/3 (7.1.5, "The `constexpr` specifier"):

> The definition of a `constexpr` function shall satisfy the following requirements:
>
> — it shall not be virtual

Comment: It is weird, for `gcc version 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1) (GCC)` [it works](http://pastebin.com/gBRT31VG)

Comment: @zaratustra: And GCC 6 [doesn't](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZTDx83wihHNGZBj8) :-(

Comment: What is the rationale.

Comment: @CiroSantilli华涌低端人口六四事件法轮功: "virtual" means "at runtime". "constexpr" means "at compile time".

Comment: polymorphic constexpr object with its state could be determined at compile time

Comment: Note that virtual constexpr will be legal in c++20. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: Could you please explain the reason behind this prohibition?

Answer (score 34):

Up through C++17, `virtual` functions could not be declared `constexpr`. The general reason being that, in `constexpr` code, everything happen can at compile time. So there really isn't much point to having a function which takes a reference to a base class and calls `virtual` functions on it; you may as well make it a `template` function and pass the real type, since you *know* the real type.

Of course, this thinking doesn't really work as `constexpr` code becomes more complex, or if you want to share interfaces between compile-time and runtime code. In both cases, losing track of the original type is easy to do. It would also allow `std::error_code` to be more `constexpr`-friendly.

Also, the fact that C++20 will allow us to do (limited) dynamic allocation of objects means that it is very easy to lose track of the original type. You can now create a `vector<Base*>` in `constexpr` code, insert some `Derived` class instances into it, and pass that to a `constexpr` function to operate on.

So C++20 [allows `virtual` functions to be declared `constexpr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1064r0.html).

Comment: Ooh, interesting; I actually just ran into a case where compile-time polymorphism would be _really_ useful yesterday, while attempting to set up a compile-time tag list of potentially variable length to aid with other compile-time tasks.  Using a `const` reference to an empty base to allow array size to be a NTTP on the actual tag list was a relatively clean way to solve one of the issues, but introduced its own problems due to the lack of `constexpr virtual`.  Glad to see this'll be available soon!

Comment: @JustinTime NTTP?

Comment: @curiousguy: Non-type template parameter.

Answer (score 18):

> Can virtual functions be constexpr?

Yes. **Only since C++20**, virtual functions can be `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++20 and later, a constexpr function can be virtual, and a constructor can be defined as constexpr when the enclosing class has any virtual base classes.