# Raise compile-time error if a string has whitespace

Tags: c++, constexpr, compile-time, library-design

I have a base class that is intended to be inherited by other users of the code I'm writing, and one of the abstract functions returns a name for the object. Due to the nature of the project that name cannot contain whitespace.

```
class MyBaseClass {

  public:

    // Return a name for this object. This should not include whitespace.
    virtual const char* Name() = 0;

};
```

Is there a way to check at compile-time if the result of the `Name()` function contains whitespace? I know compile-time operations are possible with `constexpr` functions but I'm not sure of the right way to signal to code users that their function returns a naughty string.

I'm also unclear on how to get a `constexpr` function to actually be executed by the compiler to perform such a check (if `constexpr` is even the way to go with this).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace

Comment: @dixit_chandra **compile-time**.

Comment: I don't believe there's *any* way to check a string at compile time.

Comment: @MarkRansom `std::isspace` is defined with `#define` directives so it's available in `constexpr` contexts.

Comment: That checks a single character, not a string. I stand by my statement until proven otherwise.

Comment: I'm using `const char*`, not `std::string`, and for loops and array indexing are also available in `constexpr`...

Hence my issue is more about checking the return value of a virtual function, not just a string (`const char*`) in general.

Comment: Do you have a way to prevent a derived class from reading its name from a file (at program start-up)?

Comment: @JaMiT declaring the pure virtual function as `constexpr` as in my selected answer accomplishes this. Unless there's a way to read files in a `constexpr` context. Which wouldn't even surprise me at this point.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann So this shouldn't surprise you: [`std::embed`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1040r0.html#design.goals)

Comment: Wow. C++ is just a super efficient version of JavaScript now isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is possible in C++20.

Here is my attempt:

```cpp
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

constexpr bool is_whitespace(char c) {
    // Include your whitespaces here. The example contains the characters
    // documented by https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/iswspace
    constexpr char matches[] = { ' ', '\n', '\r', '\f', '\v', '\t' };
    return std::any_of(std::begin(matches), std::end(matches), [c](char c0) { return c == c0; });
}

struct no_ws {
    consteval no_ws(const char* str) : data(str) {
        std::string_view sv(str);
        if (std::any_of(sv.begin(), sv.end(), is_whitespace)) {
            throw std::logic_error("string cannot contain whitespace");
        }
    }
    const char* data;
};

class MyBaseClass {
  public:
    // Return a name for this object. This should not include whitespace.
    constexpr const char* Name() { return internal_name().data; }
  private:
    constexpr virtual no_ws internal_name() = 0;
};

class Dog : public MyBaseClass {
    constexpr no_ws internal_name() override {
        return "Dog";
    }
};

class Cat : public MyBaseClass {
    constexpr no_ws internal_name() override {
        return "Cat";
    }
};

class BadCat : public MyBaseClass {
    constexpr no_ws internal_name() override {
        return "Bad cat";
    }
};
```

There are several ideas at play here:

- Let's use the type system as documentation as well as constraint. Therefore, let us create a class (`no_ws` in the above example) that represents *a string without whitespaces*.
- For the type to enforce the constraints at compile-time, it must evaluate its constructor at compile time. So let's make the constructor [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval).
- To ensure that derived classes don't break the contract, modify the virtual method to return `no_ws`.
- If you want to keep the interface (i.e returning `const char*`), make the virtual method private, and call it in a public non-virtual method. The technique is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170688/private-virtual-method-in-c).

Now of course here I am only checking a finite set of whitespace characters and is locale-independent. I think it would very tricky to handle locales at compile-time, so maybe a better way (engineering-wise) would be to explicitly specify a set of ASCII characters allowed in the names (a whitelist instead of a blacklist).

The above example would not compile, since `"Bad cat"` contains whitespace. Commenting out the `Bad cat` class would allow the code to compile.

[Live demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/95GMK1r31)

Comment: A useful application of C++20's `constexpr virtual`.  Bravo!

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need, very impressive. But is there an easy and `consteval`-friendly way to check a `string_view` for *any* whitespace, not just the space character?

Comment: Also, for anyone else attempting to use this: some compilers may report `expression ‘<throw-expression>’ is not a constant expression` rather than reporting the `logic_error`. But if the line is evaluated at all it means the condition to throw the exception was true and the string is invalid.

This is the case for me with g++ version 11.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the names themselves are all specified at compile-time, there's no way to assert they contain no whitespace characters prior to a runtime check.

Comment: What if I change the pure virtual declaration to `constexpr` so the return values must be specified at compile-time?

Comment: A `constexpr` function is not *guaranteed* to actually be called at compile-time, it only grants the compiler *permission* to call it, if it so chooses. `constexpr` functions can also be used at runtime, too. And besides, polymorphic function calls don't work at compile-time, anyway

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is no longer true in C++ 20. Virtual functions can now be declared `constexpr`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55972550/539997